# Request interrupted - Paw

Tags: paw-app

No matter what I do, I always get this error on the console. It works on other machines, but not in mine. Postman works with the same service. How to solve?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** this bug has been now fixed in [Paw 2.3.4](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.3.4). And we confirm that the workaround below wasn't resolving the "Request Interrupted" issue most users were having. You can update in *Paw* menu > *Check for Updates…*

---

One quick way to solve this is to go to the Paw menu > Preferences > HTTP and pick another HTTP library:

[image: Change the HTTP library in Paw]

To be able to send exactly what users are entering (including any kind of headers, GET requests with a body) and display exactly what servers are returning (keeping the exact raw bytes, the order of headers) Paw has its own custom HTTP library that can do all this kind of stuff. Unfortunately, it's not yet as stable as standard libraries, hence the possibility to choose another alternative.

Comment: I'm already using this setting and the problem persists. I'm using this address (included with Paw): https://echo.luckymarmot.com

Comment: @MarceloDosSantos so it fails also with ASIHTTPRequest and NSURLConnection? this is very strange… it looks like a setting or a DNS config issue… do you have a proxy set either system wide or in Paw under Preferences > HTTP?

Comment: No. I don't have a proxy.

Comment: I've a latest release installed and the problem still persists. I addition that I'm also having weird problem with authentication. It comes back with,

*Login Error*
_Authentication Error (Couldn't store credential)_